# What two continuous functions from $[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ failed the parallelogram rule?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C([a,b],\mathbb C)$ with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Show that $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is not induced by an inner product.

Hence to show that this norm is not induced by an inner product we must prove that the parallelogram rule fails with specific f and g functions that belong to the set X. The parallelogram rule is

$\|f-g\|^2_\infty +\|f+g\|^2_\infty = 2(\|f\|^2_\infty+\|g\|^2_\infty)$

I have been trying for a couple of days to find the particular f and g to make this statement false. Can someone help?

Note: $\|f\|_\infty=\sup(|f(x)| \text{ where }x\in [a,b])$.

Comment: You're saying you found functions _satisfying_ the parallelogram law? Perhaps you were colossally unlucky...?

Comment: Try with a couple of functions with disjoint support

Comment: What is a disjoint support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\in [0,1/4],\\1/2-x,&x\in[1/4,1/2],\\0,&x\in[1/2,0]\end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1-x,&x\in [3/4,1],\\x-1/2,&x\in[1/4,1/2],\\0,&x\in[0,1/2]\end{cases}$$

They are continuous, but hey don't satisfy parallelogram law.

They idea is to get two functions with disjoint support and the same norm, so their sum and difference still has the same norm.

**edit** Example of norm calculation.

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)| = \max\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1/4]}|f(x)|,\sup_{x\in[1/4,1/2]}|f(x)|,\sup_{x\in[1/2,1]}|f(x)|\right)$$
$$=\max\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1/4]}|x|,\sup_{x\in[1/4,1/2]}|1/2-x|,\sup_{x\in[1/2,1]}0\right)$$
$$=\max\left( 1/4 ,\sup_{x\in[1/4,1/2]}(1/2-x), 0\right)=\max\left( 1/4 , 1/4,  0\right)=\frac 14.$$

Comment: This might sound stupid but how do you take the norms of a piecewise function

Comment: @UsernameUnknown by the definition of the norm that you provided=) Note that you don't need a continuous function for that supremum to be a norm. Anyways, the functions I provided are continuous, positive, and it's easy to find their supremum by sketching a graph.

Comment: Can you just show me for f

Comment: @UsernameUnknown see edit.